# What's up with document.domConfig on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception, dom

I was iterating over properties of `document` when I ran into an interesting phenomena in Firefox, `document` claims to support the property `domConfig` although [MDC says it isn't implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.domConfig) but when I try to retrieve the property I get an exception:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIDOM3Document.domConfig]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: javascript:alert(typeof(document.domConfig)) ::  :: line 1"  data: no]

The following shows the behaviour, both Chrome and IE are consistent (I haven't checked Opera) in saying that `domConfig` is not a property of window but Firefox claims it is but can't retrieve it (copy paste into URL field since I can't get markdown to give a link).

```
/* true in FF, false in other browsers */ 
javascript:alert("domConfig" in document)
/* exception in FF, 'undefined' in other browsers */
javascript:alert(typeof(document.domConfig))
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me: the documentation says it's not implemented, and sure enough when you try to access it you get a "NOT_IMPLEMENTED" exception. "Native" objects like "document" are portals into the guts of the browser, so the fact that the C++ object exposes a property to Javascript that triggers the exception means only that it's there as a stub.  How is this causing a problem for you?

Comment: @Pointy, so why does it appear as a property? I have to skip it when iterating properties.

Comment: It appears I guess because the Mozilla developers left it there exposed. I'm not exactly sure how the Javascript <--> C++ boundary works, but I'm going to guess that there's a function being called that throws that NOT_IMPLEMENTED exception.  You could always wrap your "property sniffer" in a try/catch block and just ignore exceptions like that.

Comment: Still, @Motti has a point. Why would something be there to be iterated through when an attempt to even *get its type* throws an exception? Sounds pretty stupid to me. It forces the developer to prepare for exceptions of an unknown type, and to silently drop them - not good practice at all.

Comment: Remember boys and girls, defined != implemented. See Nickolay's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy's right, `domConfig` is exposed in an interface (DOM Level 3 Core [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document) - in Mozilla's source it's called [nsIDOM3Document](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/interfaces/core/nsIDOM3Document.idl#68)), but is [not implemented](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/nsDocument.cpp#6205) (see `nsDocument::GetDomConfig()`). `typeof` works by first getting the value, then determining its type (and not from the interface definition), so it's not surprising `typeof document.domConfig` throws an exception.

As for why it's been done this way, the [bug this code was added in](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212218) doesn't have any discussion about that, so we can only guess.

My guess is that for specifications Mozilla intended to implement it made sense to finalize ("freeze" in Mozilla's terms) the interfaces, so that they could be used from binary code without further modifications after new properties/methods of the interface got implemented. And it didn't seem to matter much one way or another.

If you're interested in hearing from the developers, you could ask in [mozilla.dev.tech.dom](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.dom/topics) or mozilla.dev.platform.