# typeof document['domConfig'] thows an error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Why does this expression:

```
typeof document['domConfig']
```

throw an error in Firefox (4)?

All the other browsers (IE9, Chrome 10, Safari 5, Opera 11) **do not** throw an error on that line!

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TvBeT/

Btw, `document.domConfig` is a property [defined in the DOM Core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Document3-domConfig).

Comment: Answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217263/whats-up-with-document-domconfig-on-firefox

Comment: @Billy - Just noticed that. Will vote to close.

Comment: @Billy Thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other browser define document.domConfig, so they return undefined.

More interesting, firefox 4 is the only browser that can run document.normalizeDocument(),
which method gives domConfig a value while it is running, merging adjacent text-nodes and adjusting the containment of bad html tags on an existing or newly created Document..

Answer (score -1):

From the [MDN page on `domConfig`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.domConfig):

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.